# Angular list of components dynamically created

Tags: angular

I have the following scenario, and I am going to use Facebook as an example:

If you look at the news/status feed within Facebook, if I was to implement something similar in Angular, would each status combined with comments and likes, be its own component, or implement it within a `*ngFor`?

Let's use some code as an example.

Example 1: not a component:

```
<ul *ngFor="let status of statusses">
    <li>{{status.description}}</li>
    <!-- some more Div tags -->
    <input id="comment" />
    <button id="comment"/>
</ul>
```

This example will have one component, for instance, `Statuses`.  This component will have an array of all `statuses`, and logic for clicking on comment button etc.

Example 2: List of components

```
<!-- List of single status components -->
<ng-template></ng-template>
```

In this example, the `Statuses` component will only have logic for retrieving statuses, and the component displaying the status, will be responsible for logic of commenting etc.

Is example two possible within Angular 4+ ?

Is this breaking down in to a too granular approach, or is this expected?

Comment: Maybe this can help --> https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1):

Actually, method 2 is the recommended way.

If you look at the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3) example you will see that there is `heroes` and a `hero-detail` component.